# Comma seperated list using brackets in query string

Tags: php, query-string

I have a query string being sent to a php file as so: participants[]=111111111,22222222,333333333 etc....

If I remove the [] it functions fine, however, if I leave it in it ignores the array for each. How can I make PHP iterate through the comma seperated values with [] on the variable name? I tried explode which also failed unless I removed the []. I need to create a for each statement for the number of values returned for that var.

I have the following PHP code:

```
$participants = $_REQUEST["participants"];
foreach($participants as $i=>$value) {
    if($value > 1) {
        // define each variable
        $id = $_REQUEST['participants'][$i];
        print "$id<br />";
    }

}
```

Comment: PHP treats fields in a post header that have [] in the end as arrays and translates them automatically into php arrays.

Comment: In your query string, what do you need the brackets for?

Comment: Brackets are coming from IOS app. can t remove them until we update the app in the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using explode() in your code.
Since you can't remove the brackets in your query string, you may test the following code:

```
$participants = explode(',', $_REQUEST["participants"][0]);
foreach($participants as $i=>$value)
{
    if(intval($value) > 1) {
        // define each variable
        $id = $participants[$i];
        print "$id<br />";
    }
}
```

The output now is:
111111111
22222222
333333333

Comment: Cant remove brackets as it comes from an IOS app. Any other ideas? I already had my code working without the brackets. Just need to know how to make it work with them.

Comment: I just updated my answer with new code that may work with the brackets in the query string.

Comment: Almost, I get 2<br> and that's it. Your previous code returned 2<br> 0<br>

Comment: should be returning the number for each comma seperated value. So 11111111<br>22222222<br> etc....